# Why cannot c++ compiler find operator<<

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, operator-overloading

Why cannot compiler find operator<<. Where is the compiler looking into to find the definition of operator<< when it encounters the line 
`cout <<f.some_func()<<endl;`

The error:
`error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<std::vector<int> >’)
   cout <<f.some_func()<<endl;`

`some notes:....`
`error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
   cout <<f.some_func()<<endl;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct Bar
{
   int y;
};

class Foo
{
  int x;
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Foo& f)
  {
      os << "Foo: " << f.x << endl;
      return os;
  }
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Bar& b)
  {
      Foo f;
      os << "Bar b.y: " << b.y << endl;
      os << "Bar f.x: " << f.x << endl;

      return os;
  }
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, vector<vector<int> > const&  vec ){
      os << 5;
      return os;
  }

public:
  Foo(int x = 10):x{x}{}
  vector<vector<int> > some_func(){
    vector<vector<int> > abc(3, vector<int>(3));
    int x = 900;
    return abc;
  }
  //If I do this
  void wrapper(){
    cout << this->some_func() << endl;
  }

};


int main()
{
  Bar b { 1 };
  Foo f{ 13 };
  cout << f << endl;
  //cout << b << endl;
  cout <<f.some_func()<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the mechanism by which it looks doesn't consider operators defined in a class `Foo` that need to be applied on arguments from namespace `std`. And btw, I suggest you kick the habit of `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like this that are defined as friends inside the class have rather unusual name lookup rules. They're free functions, but their names are inside of the class of which they're a friend. Because of this, they're only found via argument-dependent lookup.

For that to work, however, at least one of the arguments has to be something like a reference to an object of the class in which it's defined, or else something defined inside that class.

In your case, the arguments are an `iostream` and a `vector<vector<int>>`, neither of which has any relationship to `Foo`, so the compiler doesn't use argument-dependent lookup to find the function inside of `Foo`.

The obvious way to make it work is to have the overloads for `Foo` and `Bar` inside the definitions of `Foo` and `Bar`, and the overload for `std::vector<vector<int>>` outside any class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct Bar
{
    int y;

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Bar& b)
    {
        return os << "Bar b.y: " << b.y;
    }
};

class Foo
{
    int x;
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Foo& f)
    {
        return os << "Foo: " << f.x;
    }

public:
    Foo(int x = 10) : x{ x } {}

    vector<vector<int> > some_func() {
        vector<vector<int> > abc(3, vector<int>(3));
        int x = 900;
        return abc;
    }
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, vector<vector<int> > vec) {
    return os << 5;
}

int main()
{
    Bar b{ 1 };
    Foo f{ 13 };
    cout << f << '\n';
    cout << b << '\n';
    cout << f.some_func() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so whats the workaround if I want to use operator<<  inside one of the class functions for vector and another outside the class but with its object like in main

Comment: Ok, I make it free function now, lets say I add the following func in Foo:
It will give me compiler error now. I already defined operator << as free function
  void wrapper(){
    cout << this->some_func() << endl;
  }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. You do have to define `operator<<` before you call it, but other than that, there's no difficulty with calling it from a member function at all.

Comment: I just edited my post. The function wrapper(). The compiler isn't able to find operator<< if I make it global free function.

Comment: @KAY_YAK: Works fine for me. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ff801d18b00ea5d

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put the body before class definition.  Btw lets say I have the following relationship 
Shape<---Triangle<---IsoTriangle and Triangle<--AcuteTriangle
Here Shape and Triangle are abstract classes and IsoTriangle is a concrete class.
Now, I have a wrapper function with vector<vectror<int>> return. Now, I want to overload operator<< but the code is same for every class. Where should I put the code so that its visible for all classes?

Comment: @KAY_YAK: You'd put the overload of `operator<<` before any call to it. It apparently doesn't depend on any of the classes, so the easy choice would be to just put it before any of them.